# Can't change nodify application url after Nodejitsu deployment

Tags: shopify, nodejitsu

Edit: So it looks like the problem was the underscore in the URL.  I replaced it with a dash (-) and it works fine.

My app is working ok on localhost.

After deploying to Nodejitsu, I am attempting to edit the app from my partner dashboard and change the 'Application URL' from

```
http://localhost:3000
```

to

```
http://mdausmann.guidebyside_shopify.jit.su
```

I get the following message on the edit page...
2 errors prohibited this api client from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:

```
Callback url is invalid
Application url is invalid
```

This doesn't seem to make much sense to me as it is a valid url and is up etc.  I also tried adding a :80 but that didn't work.

Any Ideas?
Michael

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your URL isn't what shopify is expecting.  It seems to be originating from the underscore.

For example if you set your callback URL to

```
http://fabulous.dancing_pandas.com
```

it won't work.  But if instead you set your callback url to:

```
http://fabulous.dancingpandas.com
```

Things will work fine. This is a bug on Shopify's end, but I guess the work around would be to change your `guidebyside_shopify` to guidebysideshopify or something similar.  That should help you with this bug until it gets fixed.

**Edit**

There was a minor mistake when I was testing out some things.  And after a bit of research into the [ruby URL library](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/171362) I discovered that underscores aren't permitted according to the RFC.  So you'll need to fix your applications URL and this isn't a bug in Shopify.